# Unable to import beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-module

I'm using Python.7.10 and have installed beautifulsoup using pip. The package was installed successfully. But when I'm trying to import beautifulsoup,  I'm getting this error:

```
ImportError: No module named beautifulsoup
```

I checked the list of my installed modules and I found the beautifulsoup module in the installed modules list:

[image: Beautiful soup Installed Picture]

[image: Error while importing]

[image: Installed module list]

Comment: Did you read the documentation? The module is called `bs4` if you installed `beautifulsoup4`, otherwise `BeautifulSoup`. But you don't want to install the latter, BeautifulSoup 3 has been discontinued 3 years ago.

Comment: Please always post *text*, not a screenshot of your console.

Comment: How to delete installed module in python ?

Comment: `pip uninstall beautifulsoup`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You installed BeautifulSoup version 3; the module is called `BeautifulSoup` with capital `B` and `S`:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

See the [*Quickstart* documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Quick%20Start).

You really want to *upgrade* to BeautifulSoup 4. BeautifulSoup 3 was discontinued in 2012.

To install version 4, use:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

and import `bs4`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Do study the [project documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) before continuing however.

Comment: Why do I have to import beautifulsoup4 from bs4 if the module name is beautifulsoup4? I am used to install a package and import it directly. Please, forgive me if this is a stupid a question.

Comment: @Felipe: the *PyPI project name* is `beautifulsoup4`. The project name and the module(s) the project installs do not have to match. A project can contain more than one top-level name too. *Most* PyPI projects have names matching the module they install, but not all.

Comment: @Felipe: see [Are there rules for naming single-module Python packages?](//stackoverflow.com/a/33809427) for some more examples.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Martijn. I did not know that and I will take a look at the link you provided.